# Find product id of the top selling product of each day, using total sold quantity to determine the top selling product

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, adventureworks

Adventureworks2008R2 database.

The result I want is each day the MaxQantity sold, for example, OrderDate 2007-09-01 shall have the max quantity of 96 only, but my query gives me 3 different results from the same day, maybe because it is considering the timestamp as well

```
SELECT DISTINCT CAST(oh.OrderDate AS DATE) OrderDate, (od.ProductID),SUM(od.OrderQty) MAXOrderQty
FROM Sales.SalesOrderDetail od
Inner Join Sales.SalesOrderHeader oh
ON od.SalesOrderID = oh.SalesOrderID
GROUP BY od.ProductID, CAST(oh.OrderDate AS DATE), od.OrderQty
ORDER BY SUM(od.OrderQty) DESC
```

[image: Screenshot of my output]

Comment: You're query gives you 3 results as you have 3 products. Remove `ProductID` from your `SELECT` and `GROUP BY`. You also don't need the `DISTINCT`.

Comment: It still doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write `CTE` and self `JOIN` on `MAX` Qty by `date`

```
;WITH CTE(OrderDate,ProductID,MAXOrderQty) AS(
    SELECT  CAST(oh.OrderDate AS DATE) OrderDate,od.ProductID,SUM(od.OrderQty) MAXOrderQty
    FROM Sales.SalesOrderDetail od
    Inner Join Sales.SalesOrderHeader oh
    ON od.SalesOrderID = oh.SalesOrderID
    GROUP BY od.ProductID, CAST(oh.OrderDate AS DATE)
)
SELECT t1.* 
FROM CTE t1 INNER JOIN (
    select OrderDate,MAX(MAXOrderQty) 'MAXOrderQty'
    from CTE 
    GROUP BY OrderDate
)t2 on t1.OrderDate = t2.OrderDate and t1.MAXOrderQty = t2.MAXOrderQty
```

Answer (score 1):

It's much easier addressing problems like this with window functions. In this case, `rank` should do the trick:

```
SELECT OrderDate, ProductID, MaxOrderQty
FROM   (SELECT OrderDate, ProductID, MaxOrderQty,
               RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY OrderDate ORDER BY MaxOrderQty DESC) AS rk
        FROM   Sales.SalesOrderDetail) s
WHERE  rk = 1
```